# Does uninstalling Xcode with the --all option remove everything?

Tags: xcode, uninstallation

The documentation says:

> To uninstall Xcode developer tools on the boot volume along with the  directory, from
>   a Terminal window type:
>   `$ sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all`
>
> To remove the underlying developer content on the boot volume, but leave the 
>   directory and supporting files untouched, from a Terminal window type:
>   `$ sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=systemsupport`

My confusion is because the first option doesn't mention anything about removing "the underlying developer content".

Is the second option a subset of the first? Or do I need to run both to completely remove all traces of Xcode from my system?

Is this "underlying developer content stored in the Xcode directory or some place else? If it's in some other place, it sounds like it would be hard to remove if you have two versions of Xcode installed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the second option seems to be a subset of the first. I am no expert, but I have been toying around with custom installations for the past 48 hours (with little breaks.) Remember when you installed xcode it asked if you wanted to install "system support" (or system tools) and/or "unix tools"? Well you can uninstall any one of those, or all of them.

Just type this:
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --help